# Collision detection between a curve an line where the curve has no obvious equation

Tags: python, math, geometry

I am using Perlin noise to create a 2d landscape. What is the easiest / most efficient way to do the following:

If I pick any point above the Perlin noise line, then provide a vector / direction how can I tell whether a line coming from that point in the given direction:

a. touches the line?

b. if it touches the line, what is the distance from the original point to the point at which the line collides with the Perlin noise line?

I know how to do this if it were straight lines but this is not the case. BTW I'm doing this with pygame, so if any pygame specific functions can be used that is great.

A diagram: [image]

Sorry but I can't give you any details about the specifics of my Perlin noise yet it is still in development.

I don't think checking every x value of the noise is viable due to the fact I am working on a pixel scale, thus the following situation could occur:

[image]

In this case the pink represents the line I'm testing for and the blue represent the pixel plot of my Perlin noise. In this case checking every value would fail to yield the correct result

Someone asked for an example of the Perlin noise, a point's `x` value is the index of the list, the `y` value is `list[x]`.

Noise:

```
[0.0, 1.2950474273729242, 2.302306537551865, 3.021777330536823, 3.4534598063277975, 3.597353964924789, 3.4534598063277975,
 3.021777330536823, 2.302306537551865, 1.2950474273729242, 0.0, 3.910627653655182, 6.952226939831434, 9.124797858528757,
 10.428340409747152, 10.862854593486615, 10.428340409747152, 9.124797858528757, 6.952226939831434, 3.9106276536551814,
 0.0, 2.3925761696810253, 4.253468746099601, 5.5826777292557255, 6.3802031191494, 6.646044915780626, 6.3802031191494,
 5.5826777292557255, 4.253468746099601, 2.3925761696810257, -0.0, -1.3453317543307322, -2.3917008965879676,
 -3.1391074267717074, -3.5875513448819514, -3.7370326509187, -3.5875513448819514, -3.139107426771708,
 -2.3917008965879676, -1.345331754330732, 0.0, 1.9499487707658063, 3.4665755924725437, 4.549880465120213,
 5.199863388708816, 5.4165243632383495, 5.199863388708816, 4.549880465120213, 3.4665755924725437, 1.9499487707658059,
 0.0, 2.025500578709133, 3.6008899177051252, 4.726168016987977, 5.401334876557688, 5.626390496414258, 5.401334876557688,
 4.726168016987977, 3.6008899177051252, 2.025500578709133, 0.0, 1.71832580933312]
```

For example the first point is (0, 0) the second is (1, 1) the third is (2, 2) BTW I'm rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: Is doing it the other way round an option? Instead of following a well defined straight line and trying to find out whether/where it touches an undefined curve, follow instead the noise (while rendering it, or while doing anything else with it for which you have to process each part....) and check whether the point you are looking at is touch the well-defined line.

Comment: I guess, i should have mentioned that i need to do this for about 10 - 20 other lines, BUT they will all have the same gradient

Comment: How would i go about doing this?

Comment: You said "I know how to do this if it were straight lines" so I thought you knew... Look at each part of the curvve line (assuming you have to do that anyway in some part of your program) and answer the question "Does this point lie on the straight line?".

Comment: But then i would be checking for collision between a point and a line, this causes problem when working with pixels and only integers, it is possible that this approach wil result in some cases where it appear the line doesnt intersect when it should

Comment: To be honest i would prefer if i could do it from the line not the noise

Comment: I think it is time to provide a [mre] with 10 sample lines and a sample of a noise similar to what you have. If you "cant give you any details about the specifics of my perlin noise yet it is still in development" and can't decide on a generic noise method for which an answer would be helpful, then I think it is not the time to ask this question yet.

Comment: it is very simple, for every x value of the noise there is a y value, given a point (x, y) and an angle (radians or degrees whatever is easier) does the line interesect the noise yes / no if so then what is the (x, y) of the point, then the distance can be worked out

Comment: In that totally generic form, the answer is "Check at each x against each of the lines." If you can be more specific about the noise then the solution can be more specific. If you can add more focus to the question please do so by [edit]ing. It really needs more focus.

Comment: I've edited the question and explained the flaws with that approach

Comment: You can prevent that newly described problem by splitting the noise line into small pieces of straight lines. Maybe even more than pixel to pixel. Make line segments every 5 pixels. For collision detection that is probably precise enough. Drawing can still be on pixel precision.

Comment: If the line is always steeper than the noise, then you can do a binary search along the length of the line.  Otherwise the line could cross the noise many times and finding the first intersection is tricky.

Comment: Fair point, would be annoying though but it is probably the way to go

Comment: @MattTimmermans i cant guarantee that, i just need to find the first point of intersection

Comment: The appropriate thing to do in the context of a game will be an approximation.  Exactly what kind of approximation may be appropriate depends on a lot of particulars that you're not telling us.

Comment: although im using pygame, it is a physics simulation, i just need the distance to be able to detect differences of about 2 pixels

Answer (score 0):

Binary search via a line segment intersection check seems like it would work.

Pick two points definitely on opposite sides of the angle line (if needed do the same with the angle line, pick two points definitely on opposite sides of the noise). Confirm that the two line segments intersection. Then pick a point points between those point (probably can just use the mean point `(X1+x2)/2, (Y1+Y2)/2`) to check the line segments to see if they also cross. Discard the segment(s) that do not intersect have an intersect with the angle line. Do this for both segments (so you increasingly get closer from both sides).

Only potential issue is if there are multiple points of intersection. Though in that case, you can just split the single binary search into two binary searches as needed, until all intersections are found, or whatever you feel makes the most sense.